# Deploy React Native Expo for Android: error Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'

Tags: react-native, deployment, expo, mobile-application, gradlew

Trying to deploy my react native project, got as far as putting eas build --platform android in the terminal and got this error

```
[stderr] FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
[stderr] 1: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
[stderr] > Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] 2: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I tried killing the terminal and trying again, making sure android studio is closed, and having been searching the web but to no avail. Thanks in advance!